# Can't load project after pulling: "Expected 'ENCODING' but found 'utf-8'."

Tags: c#, wpf, git, visual-studio-2012

After pulling the project (WPF application) from git,

I get this error:

[image]

What could be causing it? It worked fine before pulling it (someone else commited on the project).

Comment: The fact that it's talking about line 7274496 seems pretty odd to me. Just how big *is* that project file?

Comment: @JonSkeet Not big enough, if this GitHub page I've found is what he's referring to: https://github.com/dnizetic/foogle

Comment: The line endings in that .csproj file are unusual.  They are the Unix-like /n instead /r/n.  Not sure if that's enough to trip up the project converter but the shoe fits.

Comment: I got  Error on line 8309420. Expected 'ENCODING' but found 'utf-8'. - :P

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It appears there were some unclosed tags in my .csproject file.

Strangely though, the error above was reported instead.

Comment: @tofutim ... thank you sir, your comment sped up solving this on my end.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your .csproj extension file 
search for: <<<<<< or ====== or >>>>>>>> and remove it.

also check your web.config file for those symbols and remove them too if they exist there.

Comment: This started happening to me a lot with recent vs2019 if I got git merge conflict in csproj file and vs try to load it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was just missing a closing tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp < try this

edit - Try to open your .csproj in an editor and look for the missing tags.  You can do this via Visual Studio if you unload your project then edit your project.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

I had some strange underscore lines, I am using the tool Git Extensions, maybe this tool added this lines.. I compared a older version in notepad++ and saw this. It didn´t show in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This forum really helped me. Thank you very much. In my case my team mate merged the code and in .csproj there was end tag missing for  we had >. I opened .csproj in visual studio. Edited end tag to /> and saved the file and reloaded the project and it was fine.