# Visual Studios 2013 randomly get this error: Error on line 0. Expected 'ENCODING' but found 'utf-8'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently working on my AS Level Coursework (A Windows Form Application) and came across this error when trying to open my project:

> TankQuizV3\TankQuizV3.csproj: Error on line 0. Expected 'ENCODING' but
>   found 'utf-8'.

I poked around in the .csproj file and found and open Project tag which I closed .
The project would now open but if I attempt to open any of the forms I get this error:

The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.
This is followed by this chunk of code in the stack call:

> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>   fReload)

Any help or advice is appreciated, I've had to restart my project three times already over similar issues, Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt project file.  Where did you get it from?  Maybe try downloading it again?

Comment: What is the contents of TankQuizV3\TankQuizV3.csproj?

Comment: It isn't a downloaded file, I have written the code and designed the forms myself. If this is a corrupted file then i will have to replace my USB flash drive as this is the third time my project has done this.

Comment: TankQuizV3\TankQuizV3.csproj is computer generated code for my WIndows Forms Application, something my teacher has advised not to touch but putting in a closing tag was the only way to get my project to open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load project after pulling: "Expected 'ENCODING' but found 'utf-8'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990064/cant-load-project-after-pulling-expected-encoding-but-found-utf-8)

Comment: FWIW I would suggest trying to get a later version of VS, where issues like this have been fixed.

Comment: could be a problem with the byte order mark of the file.  Have you been editing the proj file in some text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue in the past.What you can do is try to create a new project.Add all the forms and everything from the previous project in the new project.

To add existing form :

Right click your Solution > Add existing item > Browse to the previous project folder and add **YourForm.CS**.This should include the designer and also the resources.I mean it'll copy the files to your project's directry.

But you may not see the designer first.So,just open the .cs file in code editor and u'll have the designer.

U may get a few errors in the class name or so but they can easily be fixed :) Hope this helps

Comment: You are a life saver. I'd upvote but I have less than 15 Rep, I will return and upvote once I have gained enough rep.

Comment: This same issue almost killed me a few months ago...I fixed it myself and i am glad that it helped you :)

Comment: Do I add each .cs, .resx and .designer.cs file seperately or is there a way to bring over the actual form?

Comment: just first dd the .cs,it should include the designer and resx